# Calculate $\mathscr{F}((1+t)^{-3})$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $$f(t)=\cases{\frac{1}{(1+t)^3}&t>0\\0&t<0}$$ Does:

a.$\hat{f}$ is differentiable?

b.$\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

c.$\hat{f}\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Seems like we need to calculate the transform $\hat{f}$. We know that it's the second derivative of $F(t)=\frac 1 {1+t}$ so we need only to calculate the $\mathscr{F}(F)(\omega)$ but now I got a divergent integral since $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(-i\omega t)}{1+t}dt=\exp(i\omega)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(-i\omega u)}{u}du$$ which is divergent. How can I find explicitly the transform? Can I use some other theorems to get it?

Comment: Do you know the Fourier inversion formula? What would this imply for $\hat{f}\in L^1$? Furthermore, do you know the Plancherel theorem? Is $f \in L^2$?

Comment: Do you know any theorem about $\mathscr F$?

Comment: I know the inversion formula but don't understand what's the connection here. Also I know Plancherel theorem.

Comment: Please refer to Julián Aguirre's comment below, 51 secs ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can answer the questions without computing $\hat f$. I give you hints that will allow you to find the answer.

a)$x\,f(x)$ is integrable.

b) $f$ is not continuous.

c) Is $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

By the way,
$$
\hat f(\omega)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-i\omega}}{(1+t)^3}\,dt.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how these help.

Comment: What do you know about Fourier transforms? If you are supposed to answer those questions, you must have seen the _theorems_ from which the answers follow directly.

Comment: I know that $f,xf(x)\in L^1\Rightarrow$ $\hat{f}$ is differentiable and Parseval's formula so that solves a and c but about b I'm not sure.

Comment: I am sure you also know $f\in L^1\implies\hat f$ continuous. Now think inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Yes but however I'm still not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: $\hat f\in L^1$ implies $f$ continuous.